# Laravel pagination per_page/limit does not get added to nextPageUrl

Tags: laravel

When using `Model::paginate($per_page)` the pagination is returned including the `per_page` variable. The problem is that the when you get the `nextPageUrl()` it only provides a `?page=x` url variable, so if you want to specify the `per_page` in the url e.g.

> https://example.com/api/users?page=1&per_page=100

It doesn't get added by the `LengthAwarePaginator` to the next/prev urls.

Is there something I'm missing or do I have to manually append this to the URL?

Comment: How do you set `$per_page`? If you go to the next page with `?page=x` `$per_page`  still has the same value right? So no need to send it in the URL?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to add that to every single url there's a method in your paginator that allows you to add query strings.

Laravel 5.4+ :

```php
//fetch the get parameter per_page, if doesn't exists defaults it to 100
$per_page = \Request::get('per_page') ?: 100;
$users = App\User::paginate($per_page);
$users->appends(['per_page' => $per_page])
return view('users', ['users' => $users]);
```

Old solution 5.3:

```php
//fetch the get parameter per_page, if doesn't exists defaults it to 100
$per_page = \Request::get('per_page') ?: 100;
$users = User::paginate($per_page);
$users->addQuery('per_page', $per_page);
return view('users', ['users' => $users]);
```

Comment: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::addQuery does not exist.